# Getting error while Installing react js in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-install

Iam trying to create react app using the link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial
but iam getting the below error when i run the command

> create-react-app my-app

Error

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\thirunah\Documents\Visual Studio Code\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.17 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","ar
ch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "
react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! unregistered users are not allowed to access package @timer/detect-port : @timer/detect-port
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811798/how-to-fix-error-user-admin-is-not-allowed-to-access-package)?

Comment: Yes. I checked my registry and it is same as mentioned.

Comment: Are you running in an administrative command shell? (that might help).

Comment: Yes I am running in an administrative cmd

Answer (score 0):

I had this same kind of error, but, with a different syntax.
Try to use `cmd` or VSCode terminal, create your react app in `C:\Users\thirunah`. Since I think there is a problem when trying to create react app in a long path (`C:\Users\thirunah\Documents\Visual Studio Code\my-app`).

So go to `cmd`, `C:\Users\thirunah` (`cd C:\Users\thirunah`) and write

```
create-react-app Your-app-name
```

Before that, make sure that `node` and `create-react-app` are installed.
You can install node from [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and in `cmd` write

```
npm create-react-app -g
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Ahmed, thanks for your contribution. May I suggest you [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in order to get familiar to the formatting used in questions and answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

> (npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm
>   versions)

Answer (score 0):

**Why is NPX create-react-app failing in VS Code?**

when I was trying to install

**> npx create-react-app *app name***

my vscode was crashing and I was not unable to install the whole. it was crashing in the middle of the session. So the reason was maybe because of slow internet connection. Timeout is set to 30000 ms which is 30 seconds by default. Try increasing the timeout to 60 seconds instead by adding this to create-react-app.
For that install it with the following code :

**> npx create-react-app *app name* -timeout=60000**

and for me, it again crashed and instead of "reopen" the vscode go for the "close" option and open it again. Then it will continue the process from where it is left off.
This will set the timeout to 60 seconds which will provide enough time to get the required resources from the npm registry for the new react app. And at last, you can see the command: **Happy hacking!**